# How can I retrieve row from another table in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables: `posts`, `votes` and `users`. I have written a neat code with Eloquent to retrieve just the posts where the user has not voted yet on.

```
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave("votes")
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                    ->whereBetween('posts.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subHours(48), Carbon::now()))
                    ->take(20)
                    ->get();

return response()->json(['posts' => $posts])->withCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

But also I want to retrieve user name from table users. I want to pass the data with json.

If I try to do it with query builder, it is hard to eliminate posts that have been voted already by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join manually to the user table

```
$posts = Post::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
                ->whereDoesntHave("votes")
                ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->whereBetween('posts.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subHours(48), Carbon::now()))
                ->take(20)
                ->get();
```

Or you could define a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) in the `Post` model class.

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then you use `with('user')` to retrieve data from user table.

```
$posts = Post::with('user')
                ->whereDoesntHave("votes")
                ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->whereBetween('posts.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subHours(48), Carbon::now()))
                ->take(20)
                ->get();
```

Comment: but what If I want to retrieve post relative to the current user. So now it removes posts that have been voted. But I want to remove posts that has been voted before by the current user.